# undefined symbol in prototype function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am getting an undefined symbol inside of a prototype function.  I write to console.log the 'this' and 'self' values.  The values change from the first invocation via a direct call to later calls via the callback from 'zoom'.  I have a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/eric_l/kQSTH/, and opening the console will allow one to see the error messages.  Any idea from neither 'this' nor 'self' are working correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Zoom by Rectangle</title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>

body {
  font-family: sans-serif; 
}

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

rect {
  fill: #ddd;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3.0px;
}
</style>
<p><label for="zoom-rect"><input type="checkbox" id="zoom-rect"> zoom by rectangle</label>
<table><tr><td> <div id="chart1"> </div> </td></tr></table>
<script>

var zoomRect = false;

d3.select("#zoom-rect").on("change", function() {
      zoomRect = this.checked;
    });

var Chart = function( _width, _height, _anchor )
{
var self = this;
this.anchor = _anchor;
this.margin = {top: 0, right: 12, bottom: 12, left: 36},
this.width = _width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right,
this.height = _height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

this.data = [ {x:0         , y:0},
              {x:this.width*0.25, y:this.height},
              {x:this.width*0.5 , y:this.height/2},
              {x:this.width*0.75, y:this.height},
              {x:this.width     , y:0} ];

this.xscale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, this.width])
    .range([0, this.width]);

this.yscale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, this.height])
    .range([this.height, 0]);

this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(this.xscale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(-this.height);

this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(this.yscale)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSize(-this.width);

this.zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(this.xscale).y(this.yscale).on("zoom", this.refresh);

this.svg = d3.select(this.anchor).append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
    .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
    .call(this.zoom)
  .append("g")
    .on("mousedown", function() {
      if (zoomRect)
      {
          d3.event.stopPropagation();
      }
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      if (zoomRect)
      {
          d3.event.stopPropagation();
      }
    });

this.svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", this.width)
    .attr("height", this.height);

this.line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return self.xscale(d.x) } )
    .y(function (d) { return self.yscale(d.y) } )

this.path = this.svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .datum(this.data)
    .attr("d", this.line);

this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
    .call(this.xAxis);

this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(this.yAxis);
}; // Chart

Chart.prototype.refresh = function() {
  console.log("this=" + this);
  console.log("self=" + self);
  console.log("this.svg=" + this.svg);
  console.log("self.svg=" + self.svg);
  self.svg.select("path").attr("d", self.line );
  self.svg.select(".x.axis").call(self.xAxis);
  self.svg.select(".y.axis").call(self.yAxis);
}

var charts = [];

charts.push( new Chart( 760, 400, "#chart1"));

for( var i = 0; i < charts.length; ++i ) {
    charts[ i ].refresh();
}


</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a reserved keyword, `self` is not.  Self is commonly used to close in the value of this within a function that may not be called on the object itself.  However, doing a `console.log(this)` inside your refresh function reveals it is indeed a `Chart` object.

Use `this` inside that function, not self; alternatively execute this line (though it's redundant)

```
var self = this;
```

EDIT: while self is not a reserved word, `window.self` **is** a global property.  Hence why `self` by itself, with no other contexts, will be `window`

EDIT 2: 
this line will cause the errors as stated

```
this.zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(this.xscale).y(this.yscale).on("zoom", this.refresh);
```

In particular, it's the binding of the zoom event.  From [the wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on), the function will have

> The specified listener is invoked in the same manner as other operator functions, being passed the current datum d and index i, with **the this context as the current DOM element**.

(emphasis mine).

you need to proxy the event through your Chart object, so change the binding to something like this:

```
this.zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(this.xscale).y(this.yscale).on("zoom", function() {
    self.refresh();
});
```

[updated js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQSTH/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I forgot an importent tidbit: one needs to left-click and move the mouse in the display window to observe the error.  'this' is correct for the first invocation, but not when doing a click-drag.